# Representation of an adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T \in L(H)$ be a positive self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $\operatorname{rank} T = 1$. I already know that there exist $y, z \in H$ such that $Tx = \langle x , y \rangle z$ for all $x \in H$. Now I need to show that there exists a $z_1 \in H$ such that $Tx = \langle x , z_1 \rangle z_1$ for all $x \in H$. We have the following (with $a,b \in H$).

$\langle Ta , b \rangle = \langle \langle a , y \rangle z, b \rangle  = \langle a, y \rangle \langle z, b \rangle$

$\langle a, Tb \rangle = \langle a, \langle b, y \rangle z \rangle = \langle a, z\rangle \langle b , y \rangle$

And using the fact that $T$ is self adjoint we get that

$\langle a, z\rangle \langle b , y \rangle = \langle a, y \rangle \langle z, b \rangle$

Now I probably need to choose $a$ and $b$ such that I can derive some relation between $y$ and $z$. Can anyone give me a hint on what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If you put $a=y$ and $b=z$, then you get $\left|\langle y,z \rangle\right| = \|y\|\|z\|$. When do we have "=" in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Ah yes. We have equality in Cauchy-Schwartz when $y$ and $z$ are linearly dependent, i.e. there exists a $\lambda$ such that $y = \lambda z$